# Laravel 4: hasOne seems to be using the wrong column

Tags: orm, laravel-4, relational-database

I have a relationship that I feel should be working but isn't. I have two tables, userwords and words. Each user words has a word associated with it, but when I query it, it used the wrong column. In my userwords table I have the column word_id that I want to use as the column that should match the id in the word table. So in the userwords model I have the relation defined as:

```
public function word(){
        return $this->hasOne('Word', 'id', 'word_id');
    }
```

But the problem is instead of searching the word table using the word_id out of the userwords table, it's using the id from the userwords table. Any idea on what I'm doing wrong? I still don't fully understand relations so I bet I'm doing something silly. Anyways, if you need more information or clarification, please let me know!

Answer (score 0):

I may be wrong but I can't find any place in that code where you call userwords. Could this be your problem?

Like it says [here](http://laravel.com/docs/eloquent#one-to-one):

```
class Person extends Eloquent {
    public function phone()
    {
        return $this->hasOne('Phone', 'foreign_key', 'local_key');
    }
}
```

I believe you mean that a Userword (Person above) has one user (Phone above) so you might want to have your code like this:

```
public function userword(){
    return $this->hasOne('Word', 'id', 'word_id');
}
```

(or whatever your table is called)

or the other way:

```
public function user(){
    return $this->belongsTo('userword', 'word_id', 'id');
}
```

I haven't tested this, but I hope this helps!